espeak not working properly on Pi Zero W
Espeak is not working properly for me on the Raspberry Pi Zero W.
It either drops the first word or two or doesn't work at all.
This problem appears to have been around for several years.
I am using the latest version of the OS: Debian version: 12 (bookworm)

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.
